# Blogger too date header issue

Tags: blogger

The date header is not working in the theme I am using.

I am getting a warning like this;

> Show date header
>
> > This feature is not applicable to your current theme.

how can i fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through your issue but to solve it in an effective manner can you please share the blog link and template that you are currently using. Mostly the issue is with the selected date header format. Maybe it's due to your current date header format not matching with the theme you're using. To change the date stamp format go to the blog setting and and under the formatting tab change the current date header format to other one by one and check if by switching to any one of them your date header is showed or not. If you have any other issue you can freely ask me.

Comment: I found the problem! It's happening because I'm using a v3 template. Thank you very much for your answer